# How to turn off internal Intel NUC light?

Tags: power, intel-nuc

I have 10th gen Intel NUC. When turned off there is visible internal yellowish-greenish light. I would like to turn it off (light) -- how to do it?

*I am not concerned with light pollution but power consumption. Device turned off should drain **no** power.*

Comment: If you want to be sure your NUC does not use any power, unplug it. Otherwise it likely uses standby power to, for example, keep the Ethernet interface powered so it can respond to Wake-on-LAN packets.

Comment: The amount of power drawn by a single LED light will be orders of magnitude less than is wasted by whatever power supply  is supplying it. If you want to waste no power when the unit is off then unplug it from the mains entirely. The light, while a visible indication of power drawn, is not going to be the highest power draw by a long shot.

Comment: From experience in electronics a single LED will draw 5 to 10 milliamps. Compared to most other things in the NUC that will be miniscule. Practically *any* active electronics will draw far more. For the amount of light they produce LEDs are amazingly efficient, especially compared to old incandescent or fluorescent lights which waste far more energy as heat than visible light.